# how make ajax-request through coffee script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

albums controller:

```
  def create
    @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)

    if @album.save
      flash[:success] = :album_saved
      redirect_to user_album_path(@current_user, @album)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = :album_not_saved
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

html form:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @album], remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

layouts/_head.html.erb:

```
<title>Vd</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

form it works. ajax-request create a new record in database.

I would like to add a message to the form. To do this I add the following code

assets/javascript/albums.coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_album").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#new_album").append xhr.'<p>album add successfull</p>'
   ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#new_album").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

As a result, the form is loaded on screen display follow eror message:

> ExecJS::RuntimeError in Albums#new Showing
>   /home/kalinin/rails/phs/app/views/layouts/_head.html.erb where line #3
>   raised: SyntaxError: [stdin]:8:32: unexpected string
>   `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Comment: Try changing this line `$("#new_album").append xhr.'<p>album add successfull</p>'` to `$("#new_album").append xhr.responseText`

Comment: Also try installing the gem `'therubyracer'`

Comment: responseText it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about `CoffeeScript` but when looking into the [***Guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html), it has the following code snippet

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_article").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#new_article").append xhr.responseText
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#new_article").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

So changing `$("#new_album").append xhr.'<p>album add successfull</p>'` to `$("#new_album").append xhr.responseText` should solve your problem.